# Angular 4 - Cannot read property 'subscribe' when I apply tests

Tags: angular

I am using Jasmine in my application Angular for the tests.

When I run it:

```
ng test -sm=false
```

I get the next error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at MenuComponent.ngOnInit (webpack:///C:/Desarrollo/Angular/Testing/src/app/menu/menu.component.ts?:21:25)
```

This is the file code menu.component.ts complete:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  public titleSup:string = "TITTLE DEFAULT";
  public sub:any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.sub = this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
       let title = data['titleSup'];
       this.titleSup = title;
     });

  }

  setTitle (title:string) {
    this.titleSup = title;
  }

}
```

Content file app-routing.module.ts (json):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchComponent,
    data: { titleSup: 'Search' }
  }, {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent,
    data: { titleSup: 'About' }
  }, {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent,
    data: { titleSup: 'Contact' }
  }, {
    path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

This is file code menu.component.html:

```
<div><b class="title" id="titleSup">{{titleSup}}</b></div>
```

I change the title in base to the "data" attribute of the "routes" object. The application works fine but when I run the test it gives me the error commented before.

How I can to resolved the error? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `data` after `this.route`:

```
  public titleSup:string = "TITTLE DEFAULT";
  public sub:any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.subscribe(data => {
      let title = data['titleSup'];
      this.titleSup:string = title;
    });
  }
```

Comment: To this way, it launchs the next error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRoute'

Comment: are You including `rxjs/observable`

Comment: Yes, I tested, but nothing  :(